# How can I send 2 pivot tables (from two sheets) in an Email?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, pivot-table

I have a excel with 2 sheets, each one has a pivot table.

I want to create a button which automatically send both pivot tables into **one** mail out.

I'm able to write the VBA code to send out one pivot but dont know how to send 2 together.

Here is my code, appreciate the help.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
' You need to use this module with the RangetoHTML subroutine.
' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, and Outlook 2010.
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Only send the visible cells in the selection.
    Set rng = Sheets("Supporttab").PivotTables(1).TableRange1



    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
               vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "abc@gmail.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "report"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
        ' display the e-mail message.
        .display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

**RangetoHTML**:

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2013
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Please post the `Sub RangetoHTML()` code.

Comment: @ella You should give credit that this code came from [Ron de Bruin's Website](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm).

Comment: @Degustaf  thanks for remindering. Yes this code  comes from there I will update

Comment: @Chrismas007 Just added Sub RangetoHTML() code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for. Just used a simple string with both ranges:

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
  '...
  Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
  '...
  Set rng = Sheets("Supporttab").PivotTables(1).TableRange1
  Set rng2 = Sheets("Other sheet").PivotTables(#).TableRange#
  '...
      .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) & vbCrLf & RangetoHTML(rng2)
  '...
```

Answer (score 0):

The other suggested answer does not work because RangetoHTML(rng2) needs to absolutely be RangetoHTML(rng), otherwise the function doesn't work.

e.g.

```html
  Set rng = Dealswb.Worksheets("Deals").Range("A19:L" & LR2)
    rng2 = RangetoHTML(rng)
    
    Set rng = Dealswb.Worksheets("Deals").PivotTables("PivotTable2").TableRange1
    rng3 = RangetoHTML(rng)
    

        
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
    .Display
    End With

    With OutMail
    .To = "xxx@yyy.com"
    '.CC = strCC
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Deal Summary " & Format(TodayDate, "MM/DD/YYYY")
    .HTMLBody = rng3 & "<br>" & rng2
    .Display
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
```